# The javascript to generate a table works on Chrome but fails on Internet Explorer. HOW?

Tags: javascript, html

So I got this javascript to generate a table and tested it in chrome and IE and Microsoft Edge.
I was able to successfully execute the codes on both Microsoft edge and Chrome. Only IE failed to generate this code. Any idea why?

```js
function generate() {
  var myTable = document.getElementById("generatedTable");

  var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
  table.border = '2';

  var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
  table.appendChild(tableBody);

  var rows = document.getElementById("tablerow");
  var row = Number(rows.value);

  var cols = document.getElementById("tablecol");
  var col = Number(cols.value);

  for (var y = 0; y < row; y++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);

    for (var x = 0; x < col; x++) {
      var td = document.createElement('TD');

      var cellwidth = document.getElementById("width");
      var widthcell = cellwidth.value;
      td.width = widthcell;
      var cellheight = document.getElementById("height");
      var heightcell = cellheight.value;
      td.height = heightcell;
      td.align = "center";
      td.contentEditable = "true";

      var cellID = "Cell " + x + "," + y;
      var celltextInput = document.getElementById("sample");
      var cell = celltextInput.value;

      if (document.getElementById("sample").value == "") {
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellID.toString()));
      } else {
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cell));
      }
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
  }

  myTable.appendChild(table);

}


function deleteTable() {

  var removeTable = document.getElementById("generatedTable");
  removeTable.innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<p>No. of Cols:
  <input id="tablecol" type="text" name="cols" value="3" /> </p>

<p> No. of Rows:
  <input id="tablerow" type="text" name="rows" value="3" /></p>

<p>Cell Height (in pixels):
  <input id="height" type="text" name="cheight" value="10" /></p>
<p> Cell Width (in pixels):
  <input id="width" type="text" name="cwidth" value="10" /></p>

<p>Sample Cell Data:
  <input id="sample" type="text" name="scell" /></p>

<br />
<Input type="button" class="button" button id="generate" onClick="generate()" value="Generate Table">
<input type="button" class="button" button id="delete" onClick="deleteTable()" value="Clear Table">

<hr/>

<p id=generatedTable></p>

<hr />
```

Comment: Did you check IE's console for errors?

Comment: Check IE console log, it likes to push everything there, even if it works well in another browsers.

Comment: it says SCRIPT5009: 'generate' is undefined. I checked I did put function {generate()...}

Comment: I tested the snippet in the question in IE 11 and it worked fine. The error seems weird, given that `generate` is your own function and unrelated to any IE compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check IE console for errors, you might get an idea about what's going on from there.

And also, IE has deperecated support pretty long ago, and is stuck on supporting old versions of EMCAScript. (you can see browser support [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_versions.asp). You can see IE does not support beyond ES5, for example.

I'm not sure what exactly in your code causes this, might be another part of your code, but this very well could be the cause.

you can go [here](https://caniuse.com/) and search for specific JS features and see which browsers supports them and at which version.

Comment: it says SCRIPT5009: 'generate' is undefined. I checked I did put function {generate()...}

Comment: @TryPenta how do you connect the JS file to your html file? or both on the same file

Comment: I link it with <script src="bsls-presentation.js"></script>